# How can i use margin and padding inside of bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have been creating a form by using bootstrap but the result is not ok for me. how can i make my form better?

[image]

```
           <div class="row" ng-if="model.FieldType == customTypes.Select">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-4">Seçim</label>
                            <div class="input-group col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="model.NewComboItemForSelect"/>
                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="AddToDropDownList()">+</button>
                                </div>
                         </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-8 pull-right">
                                <select class="form-control" ng-options="field.id as field.value for field in DropdownListCustomItems" ng-model="model.DropdownListCustomItem"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: add your complete code. css and html.

Comment: yes, please add this code to jsfiddle or any demo..thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm right, you are looking for something like this. This code will fix alignment issue. How ever, I don't know the *bootstrap* way for setting top-margin. In this code, I'm using a custom css for setting top margin.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label class="control-label col-md-4">Seçim</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="model.NewComboItemForSelect" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="AddToDropDownList()">+
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-4" style="margin-top: 4px">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```